Elevation profile tool never "finishes", or creates the section?
I am struggling with the elevation profile tool in QGIS, trying to get it to "finish". I draw a line through my focus area, but no results appear in the section window. It should be noted that I am using a very large 5km X 5km map, and attempting a 150m excerpt at a particular study area.
Does it work similarly to creating a new polygon layer? I've found it to not work intuitively like CAD systems where you simply double click to finish, etc.
Here is a screen capture of the issue: https://www.loom.com/share/6d12af1c3ea84114a14fe6241fe50cff?sid=4e1c1e5a-a8ba-405c-826b-e649a47377d7

Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Please [Edit] the Question to specify the exact GIS software in use and give an indication of the data you are using. If folks can't reproduce your issue, it's way more difficult for them to help.

Make sure you have selected the layer in the profile tool window list

My apologies - I thought I was posting just to a QGIS forum. Is that not the case?

"We have both kinds, Country and Western!" (#BluesBrothers) If you take the Tour, you'll see that this is not the case.

Right click and wait for the command to finish.
